# Venn Diagram issue.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In my Discrete math class we have to figure out how to draw each question into a Venn diagram. I know how to do the simple A U B and so on, I have found many examples of those. My issue is we need to draw ∪= into a Venn Diagram. I would not ask anyone to draw it for me but our professor told us that we have to look at A U B = B is A u B "shades to" B. How can i wrap my mind around this?

Comment: Do you know that $A \cup B = B$ implies $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: I understand it is a subset, so does this mean that in a Venn that the a is in the b?

Comment: Yes, this is in fact what "shaded" means I think.

Comment: Ok well this makes a bit more sense then it did 10 min ago.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, $A \cup B = B$ implies $A \subseteq B$. If you want to represent this in a Venn Diagram, you have to consider that $A$ can be the same size or smaller than $B$, as long as it is completely contained inside $B$. You can even draw a single circle for the case when $ A = B $.